# Table width reducing for a table with few long lines

Tags: tables, two-column

I am working on a table in a 2-column document. How do I get the table to fit the column

My table tex:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l|ccc|ccc}
  \hline
  Sequence & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{D-GEM} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Kerl \textit{et al.} \cite{conf/icra/KerlSC13} }\\
  %\cline{2-4} \cline{4-7}
  & $\delta=1$  & $\delta=5$ & $\delta=20$ & $\delta=1$ & $\delta=10$ & $\delta=20$ \\
  \hline
fr2/desk     &    0.0324    &  0.0706        &  0.1529   &  0.0333       & 0.0831     &   0.2217  \\
fr1/desk    & 0.0289          & 0.0486           &  0.0948   &   0.0346     &  0.1223   &   0.4286   \\
fr1/desk2   &     0.0335     & 0.0745     &   0.1818     &   0.0343     & 0.1103    &  0.3658    \\
fr1/floor   &     0.0355    &   0.0884    &  0.1988  &   0.0330     &   0.1036   &   0.3380   \\
fr1/room     &   0.0353 &   0.0981     &  0.2514  &    0.0307   &   0.1009   &   0.3399   \\
fr2/desk\_with\_person   &    0.0125    &  0.0240     &  0.0594   &     0.0137   &  0.0447   &  0.1516     \\
fr3/sitting\_halfsphere  &   0.0208 &  0.0535       &  0.1462    &    0.0181   &  0.0704   &   0.2599   \\
fr2/pioneer\_slam2   &    0.0593    &  0.1626     &   0.4447  &    0.0847   &  0.2156    &   0.4707   \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\caption{RMSE values of the Relative Pose Errors for various sequences.}
\label{tab:RPE_X1}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- `\small` for a smaller font size
- reduced space between columns (`\tabcolsep`)
- no vertical lines
- limited size for the first column with line breaks
- ...

Example that compares the unchanged table with a table of reduced width by `\small` and 75% of `\tabcolsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l|ccc|ccc}
  \hline
  Sequence & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{D-GEM} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Kerl \textit{et
  al.} \cite{conf/icra/KerlSC13} }\\
  %\cline{2-4} \cline{4-7}
  & $\delta=1$  & $\delta=5$ & $\delta=20$ & $\delta=1$ & $\delta=10$ &
$\delta=20$ \\
  \hline
fr2/desk     &    0.0324    &  0.0706        &  0.1529   &  0.0333       &
0.0831     &   0.2217  \\
fr1/desk    & 0.0289          & 0.0486           &  0.0948   &   0.0346
&  0.1223   &   0.4286   \\
fr1/desk2   &     0.0335     & 0.0745     &   0.1818     &   0.0343     &
0.1103    &  0.3658    \\
fr1/floor   &     0.0355    &   0.0884    &  0.1988  &   0.0330     &
0.1036   &   0.3380   \\
fr1/room     &   0.0353 &   0.0981     &  0.2514  &    0.0307   &   0.1009
&   0.3399   \\
fr2/desk\_with\_person   &    0.0125    &  0.0240     &  0.0594   &
0.0137   &  0.0447   &  0.1516     \\
fr3/sitting\_halfsphere  &   0.0208 &  0.0535       &  0.1462    &    0.0181
&  0.0704   &   0.2599   \\
fr2/pioneer\_slam2   &    0.0593    &  0.1626     &   0.4447  &    0.0847
&  0.2156    &   0.4707   \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\caption{RMSE values of the Relative Pose Errors for various sequences.}
\label{tab:RPE_X1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \small
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.75\tabcolsep}
  \begin{tabular}{l|ccc|ccc}
  \hline
  Sequence & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{D-GEM} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Kerl \textit{et
  al.} \cite{conf/icra/KerlSC13} }\\
  %\cline{2-4} \cline{4-7}
  & $\delta=1$  & $\delta=5$ & $\delta=20$ & $\delta=1$ & $\delta=10$ &
$\delta=20$ \\
  \hline
fr2/desk     &    0.0324    &  0.0706        &  0.1529   &  0.0333       &
0.0831     &   0.2217  \\
fr1/desk    & 0.0289          & 0.0486           &  0.0948   &   0.0346
&  0.1223   &   0.4286   \\
fr1/desk2   &     0.0335     & 0.0745     &   0.1818     &   0.0343     &
0.1103    &  0.3658    \\
fr1/floor   &     0.0355    &   0.0884    &  0.1988  &   0.0330     &
0.1036   &   0.3380   \\
fr1/room     &   0.0353 &   0.0981     &  0.2514  &    0.0307   &   0.1009
&   0.3399   \\
fr2/desk\_with\_person   &    0.0125    &  0.0240     &  0.0594   &
0.0137   &  0.0447   &  0.1516     \\
fr3/sitting\_halfsphere  &   0.0208 &  0.0535       &  0.1462    &    0.0181
&  0.0704   &   0.2599   \\
fr2/pioneer\_slam2   &    0.0593    &  0.1626     &   0.4447  &    0.0847
&  0.2156    &   0.4707   \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\caption{RMSE values of the Relative Pose Errors for various sequences.}
\label{tab:RPE_X2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The caption width will be limited according to the unknown line width.